# Hide iPad keyboard after user clicks Facebook share dialog share button

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a web app that uses the Facebook Share dialog using javascript. It works fine on the web however on the iPad, once you click the share button on iPad after typing in text, the keyboard doesn't disappear once you're back to the original page. I tried using this:

```
  $("u_0_l").click(function() {
    document.activeElement.blur();
    $("input").blur();                 
  });
```

But the same thing happens on the iPad (keyboard is still there). I don't think it's catching the id of the share button (#u_0_l) but I'm not sure what other element to tie it to. I tried putting it in the callback for the facebook button but the keyboard is still there. It is posting to FB so that's not the issue. I've googled this for so long and can't find anything useful. Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: is it a input element or a textarea?

Comment: It's a textarea to put in your message for FB.

Comment: I changed it to $("textarea").blur() and its still not working.